# Windows Task scheduling startup program, give this program to run add parameters how code implementation?

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks

Now that I've created a boot-up task plan using the schtasks command, I want to add a run parameter to the plan and how code implementation?

Because my task scheduler needs to be created with code. such as "aCMD.Format(L" SCHTASKS /Create /SC onlogon /TN JRCAutoUpdate_OnBoot /TR %s",szPath);"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do do this you should use the task scheduler in Windows. It is easier to have it call a powershell script on a C++ program

Comment: thanks，Because my  task scheduler needs to be created with code.   such as  "aCMD.Format(L" SCHTASKS /Create  /SC onlogon  /TN JRCAutoUpdate_OnBoot /TR %s",szPath);"

Comment: Great! Is that something you can't do problematically in a script?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: You can look at for example powershell to automate your jobs. This fits into devops. Please set my answer as correct.. thanks!

Comment: How do I execute the PowerShell command in C + +? I've made up my command .

Comment: You should call powershell from the task scheduler directly.

Comment: This method needs to modify the security settings for PowerShell because PS1 scripts are not allowed to run. I'll make it when I change the settings.thanks!